How to parse JSON string in TypeScript as string?
"{ $and: [{ status: { $ne: 'Completed' } }, { status: { $ne: 'Canceled' } }] }"

Getting error in JSON.parse(). Tried below  as well:
Query= "{ "$and": [{ "status": { "$ne": 'Completed' } }, { "status": { "$ne": 'Canceled' } }] }";
Query= "{ "$and": [{ "status": { "$ne": "Completed" } }, { "status": { "$ne": "Canceled" } }] }";

Getting error:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 31



You don't parse JSON "in TypeScript", which doesn't exist at runtime. 2. It has to be JSON.


In JSON the keys must be enclosed in double quotes.
Correct JSON format :
Query = {
   "$and":[
      {
         "status":{
            "$ne":"Completed"
         }
      },
      {
         "status":{
            "$ne":"Canceled"
         }
      }
   ]
}

To create string you can use JSON.stringify(Query)
